# error HRresult_fail has been returned from a call to a COM component while retrieving value from a webtable

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Could you suggest if this is a supported way? I am trying to fetch a value of webelement which is in a webtable. QTP will hang with an error `error HRresult_fail has been returned from a call to a COM component`
`set brwsr=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*")`

`set OrdrTBL=brwsr.webtable("column names:=Order No;Subject;Vendor Name;Tracking Number;Total;Assigned","cols:=7","html tag:=TABLE")`

`OrdNo=OrdrTBL.GetCellData(2,1)`

Thanks :)

Comment: If you show the relevant script lines, showing the line for which the error is reported in context, you might get useful feedback. Also, what do you mean with "QTP will hang with an error"? Either QTP hangs, or it pops up an RTE, but not both.